# Two bibliography, first as section and second as chapter

Tags: cross-referencing, bibliographies

I'm writing a document and inside it I need to put an example with its own references. For organizational reasons, I wanted to leave this first reference as a section and the main references in the normal way, as a chapter. The solutions I found here at StackOverflow are all global solutions, not local.

I'm using thebibliography environment to print it, and I need to use it in the main references.

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}


\begin{document}
\section{Main document chapter 1}
Main document that cites \cite{farias2016estudo} 

\section{Introduction}
Inside example that cites \cite{roque2012historia} and ends

\begin{thebibliography}
        \bibitem{roque2012historia} T. Roque, História da matemática, Zahar, (2012).
    \end{thebibliography}
    
\section{Main document chapter 2}
Main document citting \cite{Paulo}

\begin{thebibliography}
        \bibitem{farias2016estudo} D. G. d. Farias, {\em Um estudo do ensino de n{\'u}meros primos na Educa{\c{c}}{\~a}o B{\'a}sica}, Universidade Federal de Alagoas (2016). 
    
        \quad \hfill \url{http://www.repositorio.ufal.br/handle/riufal/2433}
        
        \bibitem{Paulo} P. Ribenboim, The little book of bigger primes, Springer Science \& Business Media, (2004).
    \end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `xpatch` to replace the `\chapter` in the definition of `thebibliography` by `\section`. If you do this within a group `{...}`, it won't effect the rest of the document.

Please note that the `thebibliography` environment has a mandatory argument for the widest label.

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Main document chapter 1}
Main document that cites \cite{farias2016estudo} 

\section{Introduction}
Inside example that cites \cite{roque2012historia} and ends

{
\xpatchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*{\bibname}}{\section*{\bibname}}{}{}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
        \bibitem{roque2012historia} T. Roque, História da matemática, Zahar, (2012).
    \end{thebibliography}
}
    
\section{Main document chapter 2}
Main document citting \cite{Paulo}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
        \bibitem{farias2016estudo} D. G. d. Farias, {\em Um estudo do ensino de n{\'u}meros primos na Educa{\c{c}}{\~a}o B{\'a}sica}, Universidade Federal de Alagoas (2016). 
    
        \quad \hfill \url{http://www.repositorio.ufal.br/handle/riufal/2433}
        
        \bibitem{Paulo} P. Ribenboim, The little book of bigger primes, Springer Science \& Business Media, (2004).
    \end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```